# Speed measure in tensorflow

Tags: performance, tensorflow

When I train my net with tensorflow, I find some problem that really confuses me.

```
#do something
start=time.time()
_ , _ = sess.run([something],feed_dict = {something})
end=time()
print(end-start)
```

In this way,the time it spent is 1.5 s .But when I use tensorboard to see the time it cost, I got about 400 ms.So is there any difference between that two ways ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The first run may be a bit slower, since the graph gets optimized. You could try running for a few warmup iterations first. `session.run` also includes overhead from copying the inputs and outputs, which TensorBoard may not pick up.

Take a look at [tfprof](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/README.md) for digging into the details of which ops are taking time inside the `run` call once things get warmed up.